# How to create complex filter in c# for Magento API

Tags: c#, api, magento

I am trying to create a complex filter in c# to get data from magento API. I already written the following code

```
MagentoService mservice = new MagentoService();
var mlogin = mservice.login("***", "****");
var result = mservice.storeList(mlogin);
var cpf = new complexFilter[2];

cpf[0] = new complexFilter
{
   key = "created_in",
   value = new associativeEntity
   {
      key = "in",
      value = "website A"
   }
};

cpf[1] = new complexFilter
{
   key = "bv_customer_number",
   value = new associativeEntity
   {
       key = "in",
       value = "Not Approved"
   }
};
var filters = new filters();
filters.complex_filter = cpf;
var result3 = mservice.customerCustomerList(mlogin, filters);
```

This code works perfect the only issue is I want to add the multiple values in my key = "created_in" with value = "website a", "website b"

Anyone got any ideas on how to properly pass multiple values for a single key?

Comment: Please help me with this. I am still looking for answer

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem by aggregating values into 1 value with `','` as separator:

```
new complexFilter
{
   key = "created_in",
   value = new associativeEntity
   {
      key = "in",
      value = "websiteA,websiteB,websiteC"
   }
};
```